# Sending multiple messages/Strings in Nearby Messages API

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, google-nearby

I'm trying to publish multiple strings in one activity (tracks, albums, artists) using the Nearby Messages API and subscribe to them and have them appear, in Textview, in another activity. When I run it, only one string ever shows up in the application, it appears in all 3 textviews. Is there a way to publish multiple strings or messages so that they may appear in separate TextViews simultaneously? Let me know if I've left anything out.
First is the publishing activity:

```
     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.content.IntentFilter;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
     import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
     import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
     import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Message;

     import static com.example.mark.prototype9.MainActivity.RETURN;


    public class MusicPlayingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
    {

public static final String TAG = "track";
public static final String TAG1 = "album";
public static final String TAG2 = "artist";

public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Message mActiveMessage, nActiveMessage, oActiveMessage;

TextView artist;
TextView album;
TextView title;
Button songfeed;


private void publish(String message, String message1, String message2) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Publishing message: " + message + message1);
    Log.i(TAG1, "Publishing message: " + message1);
    Log.i(TAG2, "Publishing message: " + message2);
    mActiveMessage = new Message(message.getBytes());
    nActiveMessage = new Message(message1.getBytes());
    oActiveMessage = new Message(message2.getBytes());
    Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, mActiveMessage);
    Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, nActiveMessage);
    Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, oActiveMessage);
    }

private void unpublish() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Unpublishing.");
    Log.i(TAG1, "Unpublishing.");
    Log.i(TAG2, "Unpublishing.");
    if (mActiveMessage != null)
        if(nActiveMessage !=null)
            if(oActiveMessage !=null) {
        Nearby.Messages.unpublish(mGoogleApiClient, mActiveMessage);
        Nearby.Messages.unpublish(mGoogleApiClient, nActiveMessage);
        Nearby.Messages.unpublish(mGoogleApiClient, oActiveMessage);
        mActiveMessage = null;
        nActiveMessage = null;
        oActiveMessage = null;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_playing);
    artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist);
    album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    songfeed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.songfeed);


    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");            //intentFilters assigned to music-playing activities in other applications
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");


    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);                                  //BroadcastReceiver listens for data broadcast by other activities


    songfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){           //commanding "songfeed" button to return user to MainActivity
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
                Intent getResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(getResult, RETURN);
            }

    });
}



public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {       //new instance of BroadcastReceiver

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String artists = intent.getStringExtra("artist");            //receiving data through IntentFilters, converting received data to String
        String albums = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String tracks = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        Log.v("tag", artists + ":" + albums + ":" + tracks);

        artist.setText(artists);
        album.setText(albums);                                       //setting String data to TextView
        title.setText(tracks);

        publish(tracks, albums, artists);


        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    }

  };

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    unpublish();
    super.onStop();
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

 }
```

Subscribing activity

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
    import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Message;
    import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessageListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;

    import static com.example.mark.prototype9.MainActivity.RETURN;
    import static com.example.mark.prototype9.MusicPlayingActivity.TAG;
    import static com.example.mark.prototype9.MusicPlayingActivity.TAG1;
    import static com.example.mark.prototype9.MusicPlayingActivity.TAG2;


    public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


GoogleApiClient nGoogleApiClient;
MessageListener mMessageListener, nMessageListener, oMessageListener;
SubscribeOptions options;


TextView track1;
TextView album1;
TextView artist1;

TextView track2;
TextView album2;
TextView artist2;

TextView track3;
TextView album3;
TextView artist3;

Button back;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pub_sub);

    nGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

    options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            //.setCallback(myCallback)
            .build();


                //data to receive
    track1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track1);
    album1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album1);
    artist1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist1);

    track2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track2);
    album2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album2);
    artist2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist2);

    track3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track3);
    album3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album3);
    artist3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist3);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);


    //Track
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
            track1.setText("Someone is listening to "+messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        }
    };
    //album
    nMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message1) {
            String messageAsString1 = new String(message1.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG1, "Found message: " + messageAsString1);
            album1.setText("from "+messageAsString1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message1) {
            String messageAsString1 = new String(message1.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG1, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString1);
        }
    };
    //artist
    oMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message2) {
            String messageAsString2 = new String(message2.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG2, "Found message: " + messageAsString2);
            artist1.setText("by "+messageAsString2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message2) {
            String messageAsString2 = new String(message2.getContent());
            Log.i(TAG2, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString2);
        }
    };



    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){           
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent getResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(getResult, RETURN);
        }
});

}

// Subscribe to receive messages.
private void subscribe() {
    try{
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscribing.");
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(nGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options );
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(nGoogleApiClient, nMessageListener, options );
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(nGoogleApiClient, oMessageListener, options );

}
    catch (NullPointerException n){
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void unsubscribe() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Unsubscribing.");
    Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(nGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener);
    Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(nGoogleApiClient, nMessageListener);
    Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(nGoogleApiClient, oMessageListener);
}




@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle b) {
    subscribe();
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    unsubscribe();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one subscription on the listener and all messages should be delivered to OnFound function for that. Based on the data you can differentiate the message and put the data in the right TextView